# Repeat scripts at same time in one script/application in Applescript

Tags: time, applescript, repeat

Repeat scripts at same time in one script/application in Applescript

I have run into a problem while coding this troll program.

What I want to do is turn volume up without the victim to be able to turn it down and run a script at same time (in one script/application). I don't know how to combine these scripts into one and have them run at the same time. This is the script.

```
on run {input, parameters}


tell application "Google Chrome"
            activate
            open location "https://youtu.be/sZFOwzEFYRA"


            repeat

                delay 0.1

                display dialog "Looooooolz" buttons {"Looooool", "Looolzz"}
                if result = {button returned:"Looooool"} then

                    if exists window "https://youtu.be/sZFOwzEFYRA" then
                        open location "https://youtu.be/sZFOwzEFYRA"
                    end if
                else

                    if exists window "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igfJIZayiy8" then
                        open location "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igfJIZayiy8"
                    end if
                end if  
            end repeat
        end tell
        return input
    end run
```

second script:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    repeat
    set volume output volume 100
    end repeat

    return input
end run
```

Comment: Would you edit your question to explain _what_ problem you have run in to?

Comment: Share more technical details: what language is it?

Comment: You need to specify your question... is it simply how to have one script call another? Search for "run script". Is it something else? It's unclear what you're doing with the t_1 variable.

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. I changed it so hopefully it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with pure AppleScript. However, you can get a similar effect using the combination of AppleScript and a shell script. Here's an example AppleScript that will display two dialogs in independent repeat loops. The "&" at the end of the first osascript command is the key to getting them running concurrently.

```
do shell script "#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'repeat
display dialog 1
end repeat' &
osascript -e 'repeat
display dialog 2
end repeat'"
```

You should be able to extend this idea to have your two scripts doing whatever terrible things you want.